# Blue Background of Current Community region

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

The new region **Current Community** in the Top-Bar has a light blue background that is not fully stretched or the background should be the same as on the other regions.

Currently it looks a little misaligned.

[image]

Comment: Intentional or not, now I can't un-notice it! :) Upvoted.

Comment: New comment notifications have the same effect (white border around the blue background, the same proportions you get when hovering over a notification).

Comment: It should fill the whole space, agreed. Also using the word "Community" doesn't sound right, the proper word that was always used is only "site". (current sites, your site etc)

Comment: @ShadowWizard We're experimenting with calling our sites communities now to minimize confusion that arises around "I'm on Stack Exchange, but now I have to go to a different site? What?". So that's intentional.

Comment: @AnnaLear but "community" sounds more social than what Stack Exchange sites actually are, especially Stack Overflow. I fear it will encourage new users to try being social (e.g. "hello fellows, I'm [name here] please help etc") then be hammered by others editing away everything but the dry code in the best case and leaving not-so-friendly comments in the worst case.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think that's a big deal. At the core, what makes each site work *is* the community. We even describe Stack Exchange that way: ["Stack Exchange is a growing network of individual communities"](http://stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Anna oh, missed that probably. So we should adapt this as well here on Meta and use "community" instead of "site"?

Comment: @ShadowWizard In my experience, people have been using the two terms interchangeably thus far anyway. My preference is for "site" and to be honest, I personally will probably forget 90% of the time. :) I don't think we need an organized effort or anything here. At least not just yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Using site everywhere is just confusing. For most people, the site should be Stack Exchange.  When you go from physics to pets, you're not changing sites, you're really just going to a different section of Stack Exchange. This isn't really some big thing, but I think there is consensus that we are going to slowly move in the direction of using communities instead of sites.

Comment: @JeremyTunnell for me Stack Exchange was the *network*, having sub *sites*. Anyway it's really not that important and I do accept your decision, guess it'll just take time to adjust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build with a bigger, wider blue.

Comment: looks better now