# How are the sites listed under "Your Community" picked?

Tags: support, top-bar, stack-exchange-button

My "Your Community" part of the SE dropdown lists Code Review, Programmers and Board & Card Games. I have an account on each of these sites, but I also have accounts on Server Fault, Super User and User Experience.

Shouldn't the latter three also be included under "Your Community" for me, or does that section contain a random selection of my accounts?

[image]

Comment: Well Code Review and Programmers are your other two high-scoring accounts, and Board & Card Games is the first alphabetically of the four that have 101 reputation. Wild guesses?

Comment: @animuson I think you are right. Highest-scoring accounts first and then the first alphabetically of the 101 rep accounts. At least on the other sites i get "stackoverflow", "meta" on top and then the other ones.

Comment: I believe they're planning to add the ability to pick one's own list there for easy access to preferred sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We pick your top 5 sites by reputation. For you, these are Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Code Review, Programmers, and then one more at random because the rest of your sites are all at 101 reputation.

Since you're on Meta, both Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow end up in the top "Current Community" section, which leaves three sites to show up under "Your Communities".

Comment: Why is Careers 2.0 being shown as a separate entry? I believe this is the reason for 4 entries instead of 5 (since every site has a meta). Can we have the option to remove items that we do not want? A link to Careers 2.0 is useless to me, for instance...

Comment: @yoda We are planning to allow customizing the "your communities" section (work on that is about to start, actually), but I'm not sure where Careers 2.0 is gonna fall there. I don't *think* we would allow removing it, to be honest, but I'm gonna have to check.

Comment: Is site/sites going to become community/communities in all the documentation? The tooltip shows sites, then you get community/communities. There's sites in lots of places...

Comment: @BillWoodger Eventually. Maybe. This is a new thing. It might or might not stick.

Comment: @BillWoodger Jeremy provides a bit more context on this [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217840/blue-background-of-current-community-region#comment706551_217840).

Comment: OK, thanks. I can see that in Jeremy's sense sites is not really accurate, but it is kind of ingrained. Community is already "us", in terms of moderated by us, etc. Community is also that diamond thing which has assorted useful purposes. Let alone everyday use and understanding of the word itself. Now Community may become something not-quite-the-same as the previous uses, primarily a "this part of our all-encompassing site" with some connotations relating to real-world "Community". Not sure about it myself. Yet. It is new.