# How does "your communities" work?

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, stack-exchange-button, communities-list

As per [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217841/how-are-the-sites-listed-under-your-community-picked#217949) your communities should show top 5 sites by reputation, but it show more than that, is it normal or bug ? I checked all my sites it list 6 sites and one of the site showing 7 sites- please see the screenshot below.

> [image: Communities List]

Comment: It's showing me top 6. The 6th is *User Experience* - I don't know what's that.

Comment: Maybe it's because there's a tie (rep-wise) for 5th place.

Comment: @michaelb958 then why it not shown in rest of the site? it also have the same criteria

Comment: @Anna - Status completed without any *rev* indicator? I see only three community and don't see Arqade even I have 123 reputation there.

Comment: @hims056 Your top 5 sites are MSO, SO, Sports, Android, and DBA. When you're looking at MSO, both it and SO are already linked from the "current community" section, so they are skipped under "your communities". Look at the site switcher at any other site except those 5, and you'll see the entire list. (FWIW, I agree that this is confusing. I'll double-check the intent here tomorrow.)

Comment: @AnnaLear - Ohh! I got it. I just viewed it from Arqade where it shows those five sites. :-)

Comment: @hims056 We're changing this as of a build later tonight. We're going to start showing all your communities to you regardless of the site you're on.

Comment: @AnnaLear - And thanks for allowing to edit your communities.

Comment: @hims056 really its a nice feature!!!!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a bug; it's supposed to only show 5 sites, but there are some goblins in our code making a different number of sites appear for some people.

We'll be evicting the goblins shortly.

Comment: Goblins/ unicorns (hamsters in the past...)... where *are* the SE servers located?

Comment: It turns out Narnia is in NYC.

Comment: Well, that explains why I only see four.

Answer (score 5):

Fun fact: order of operations matters! The goblins have been appropriately chastised, and a fix is incoming.

Note that the old list is still going to be cached for most folks for a while, but eventually it will catch up and update.

Comment: `There is also one additional quirk to this`... is that a quirk in the bug, or a quirk in the expected behavior?  If it is in the expected behavior, then what is the expected behavior, will it show `5 - 1` sites or will it show the top 5 except the site your on?  And what about if the site you are on is SO or MSO, will it hide both or just the actual one you are on?

Comment: Or is this enough of a question to warrant a MSO question?

Comment: @psubsee2003 The expected behaviour (far as I know) is to show 5-1 or, in the case of SO/MSO, 5-2 - both SO and MSO are excluded if they are in your top 5.

Comment: Ok, that confirms what I am seeing now (it is definitely new behavior).  I wasn't sure if it was the cached page slow to update or not.  Thanks

Comment: @psubsee2003 We're changing this as of a build later tonight. We're going to start showing all your communities to you regardless of the site you're on.